# pymc3内のエラー "concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
regression_conjugate = pm.Model()
with regression_conjugate:
  sigma2 = pm.InverseGamma("sigma2",alpha = 0.5*nu0,beta=0.5*lam0)
  sigma = pm.math.sqrt(sigma2)
  a = pm.Normal("a",mu = b0[0],sd = sigma*sd0[0])
  b = pm.Normal("b",mu = b0[1],sd = sigma*sd0[1])
  y_hat = a+b*x
  likelihood = pm.Normal("y",mu = y_hat,sd = sigma,observed = y)

n_draws = 50
n_chains = 4
n_tune = 1000
with regression_conjugate:
  trace = pm.sample(draws = n_draws, chains=n_chains,tune=n_tune,random_seed=123)

print(pm.summary(trace))
```

上のコードを実行しようとしたのですが、下のエラーが出てきました。

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-4e1a1fef1a74> in <module>()
     26   trace = pm.sample(draws = n_draws, chains=n_chains,tune=n_tune,random_seed=123)
     27 
---> 28 print(pm.summary(trace))

TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'
```

解決法がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら、回答お願いします。
環境とパッケージのバージョンは以下の通りです
Google Colab
pymc3 : 3.7
pandas : 1.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pymc3 のバージョン 3.7 は pandas のバージョン 1.0 以上と一緒には使えません。`join_axes` は pandas 1.0 で削除されており、pymc3 3.7 はこれを利用しています。pymc3 のバージョンを 3.8 以上に上げるか、pandas のバージョンを下げてください。

関連 issue: [FutureWarning in pm.summary(trace) when using Python 3.7](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/3606) -- pymc-devs/pymc3

Comment: バージョンを3.8にしたら解決しました。ありがとうございます。